# Как запретить использование кириллицы в названиях файлов и директорий?

Tags: windows

Как запретить использование кириллицы в названиях файлов и директорий?

Comment: В "WinServer 2008 R2" была такая возможность... Называлось как-то вроде FileScreen

Comment: @vp_arth Он есть и в поздних серверах, но в 2012 R2 я не могу создать фильтр на использование тех или иных символов в имени файла, только на тип создаваемого файла.

Comment: Хм, там можно задавать wildcards, не только `*.ext`; Другое дело, что wildcards - не регулярки и отфильтровать по классу символов действительно не получится :(

Comment: @vp_arth Я битый час ломал голову, можно ли как-то обратиться к выборке символов или хотя бы запретить использование символов с индексом старше, к примеру, 127, - ничего не получилось

Answer (score 3):

Такого штатного функционала нет: MS так долго боролась с проблемами использования non-latin characters в именах, что теперь просто не будет ограничивать пользователей в этом.

Что можно сделать самому? В теории, писать перехват/иньекцию в функции WinAPI, например CreateFile, в котором делать разбор имени на лету.